# Eulerian and Lagrangian descriptions of velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

I feel as if I understand the conceptual difference between Lagrangian and Eulerian descriptions. But I can't seem to follow the math. I have one example that I would greatly appreciate an explanation or full calculation for

[image]

Here $x_i$ denotes the position of a particle in the current configuration, and $X_i$ denotes its position in the reference configuration.

I am entirely on board on the velocity in the Lagrangian description. I cannot for the life of me figure out how the Eulerian description is computed nor why.

Can someone show me how the Eulerian description of the velocity is calculated?

I realize this belongs more in engineering than math, but the engineering stack is pretty dead.

Comment: You have to express $v_i$ in terms of the $x_i$, which means you have to first solve for $X_i$ in terms of $x_i$ (in particular, $x_2 = X_2 + X_2 v_0 t/h_0 \implies X_2 = x_2/(1 + v_0 t/h_0)$) and substitute that into the Lagrangian description of velocity.